# Firebase DatabaseException Can't convert object of type String from model

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app went crash.
I want to know if my path getting data from firebase that make it crash ?

Here are my class:

```
package com.handymanapp.handymanapplication.Model;

import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Post {

String jobname;
String jobwage;
String jobarea;
String jobenvironment;
String jobdesc;
String contactnumber;
String jobtype;
String jobtime;

public Post() {

}

public Post(String jobname, String jobwage, String jobarea, String 
jobenvironment, String jobdesc, String contactnumber, String jobtype, String 
jobtime, String imageUrl) {
    this.jobname = jobname;
    this.jobwage = jobwage;
    this.jobarea = jobarea;
    this.jobenvironment = jobenvironment;
    this.jobdesc = jobdesc;
    this.contactnumber = contactnumber;
    this.jobtype = jobtype;
    this.jobtime = jobtime;
}


public void setJobname(String jobname) {
    this.jobname = jobname;
}

public void setJobwage(String jobwage) {
    this.jobwage = jobwage;
}

public void setJobarea(String jobarea) {
    this.jobarea = jobarea;
}

public void setJobenvironment(String jobenvironment) {
    this.jobenvironment = jobenvironment;
}

public void setJobdesc(String jobdesc) {
    this.jobdesc = jobdesc;
}

public void setContactnumber(String contactnumber) {
    this.contactnumber = contactnumber;
}

public void setJobtype(String jobtype) {
    this.jobtype = jobtype;
}

public void setJobtime(String jobtime) {
    this.jobtime = jobtime;
}

public String getJobname() {
    return jobname;
}

public String getJobwage() {
    return jobwage;
}

public String getJobarea() {
    return jobarea;
}

public String getJobenvironment() {
    return jobenvironment;
}

public String getJobdesc() {
    return jobdesc;
}

public String getContactnumber() {
    return contactnumber;
}

public String getJobtime() {
    return jobtime;
}

}
```

Here my main activity:

```
package com.handymanapp.handymanapplication;



import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.handymanapp.handymanapplication.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.handymanapp.handymanapplication.Model.Post;
import com.handymanapp.handymanapplication.ViewHolder.PostViewHolder;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class joblist extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recycler_menu;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference post;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_joblist);


    post = database.getInstance().getReference().child("Advertisement-post");

    recycler_menu = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_job);
    recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    loadMenu();

}

private void loadMenu() {

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post,PostViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class,R.layout.job_item,PostViewHolder.class,post) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {
            viewHolder.jobnameview.setText(model.getJobname());
            viewHolder.jobwageview.setText(model.getJobwage());
            viewHolder.jobareaview.setText(model.getJobarea());
            final Post clickItem = model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(joblist.this,""+clickItem.getJobname(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    };
    recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);

}


}
```

My viewHolder:

```
package com.handymanapp.handymanapplication.ViewHolder;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.handymanapp.handymanapplication.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.handymanapp.handymanapplication.R;

public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {

public TextView jobnameview;
public TextView jobwageview;
public TextView jobareaview;

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

public PostViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    jobnameview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobnameview);
    jobwageview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobwageview);
    jobareaview = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobareaview);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
}
}
```

Im using push to generate id when im creating a new post, so i try to retrieve it back in recycler view. I dont know how the path of node

Here is my push:

```
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Advertisement-post").push();
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace for the crash? You can get it from adb logcat - or even from Firebase, if you have crash reporting set up - to show you where the problem is, and precisely which string it's failing to convert to a model. Once you've identified that, please edit it into your question (if that doesn't just solve it for you).

Comment: its ok, i already found the problem. the model class name must be the same with my firebase node.

Comment: So you solved the issue? If not, please add your database structure.